# How do I Join tables the order by all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting "Union" 5 Tables and the "order by" the [Date/time]. This works well but the problem is the result is 225000+ rows. this will not fit into excel.

I tried to limit the number of rows By "select top #" which limits the size but the top is the first in data I need the last in or most current data

```
SELECT top 1000 [Timestmp]
 ,[Audience]
 ,[Severity]
,[Verbosity]
,[UserFullName]
FROM [PD_SQL_DB].[dbo].[Client1_DiagList]
wHERE [aUDIENCE]='8' AND [SEVERITY] = '4'AND [VERBOSITY] = '0'
Union
SELECT top 1000 [TimeStmp]
,[MessageText]
,[Audience]
,[Severity]
,[Verbosity]
,[UserFullName]
FROM [PD_S`enter code here`QL_DB].[dbo].[Client2_DiagList]
WHERE [AUDIENCE]='8' AND [SEVERITY] = '4'AND [VERBOSITY] = '0'
 Order by [TimeStmp] desc
```

With Query it only gives me the top 1000 oldest rows. What is another way to limit the number or rows and order by desc.

Comment: Excel 2007 and later supports 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: `Order by [TimeStmp] desc` returns the newest rows and not the oldest.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between "union" and "union all"? The difference might be important to your goal. And what exactly is your goal? Do you want (x) rows from all the rows generated by the union? Or do you want (x) rows from each select statement within the union? Joel has given you the former.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest the `UNION` inside another `SELECT` and do the `TOP`/`ORDER BY` there:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM (
    SELECT [Timestmp]
      ,[Audience]
      ,[Severity]
      ,[Verbosity]
      ,[UserFullName]
    FROM [PD_SQL_DB].[dbo].[Client1_DiagList]
    WHERE [aUDIENCE]='8' AND [SEVERITY] = '4'AND [VERBOSITY] = '0'

    Union

    SELECT [TimeStmp]
      ,[MessageText]
      ,[Audience]
      ,[Severity]
      ,[Verbosity]
      ,[UserFullName]
    FROM [PD_S`enter code here`QL_DB].[dbo].[Client2_DiagList]
    WHERE [AUDIENCE]='8' AND [SEVERITY] = '4'AND [VERBOSITY] = '0'
) t
ORDER BY [TimeStmp] DESC
```